# Displaying Zero behind point at decimal number on handsontable

Tags: handsontable

I'm trying to display ***123.00*** on handsontable. My latest handsontable (0.34) only display ***"123."*** on the cell. Is there any way to display it as "123.00"?

If the number is not zero behind the point, it will display properly. For example ***123.45*** will be displayed ***123.45***